# macOS - Setting font-size in <html> dynamically doesn't change line height

Tags: html, css, macos

I created a plugin that changes the  font-size dynamically using javascript. In short, it gets the current width of the screen and does some math to set the html font-size to the new percentage.

It works flawlessly in everything (including IE 10) EXCEPT for macOS. It also works in iOS.

So, from my understanding, when you change the font-size on the html element, it should scale the line-height proportionality. It does that as expected, but not in macOS. In macOS it keeps the original line-height.

The problem this is causing is that on smaller screens (macbooks) the font-size shrinks, but the line-height is still blown out.

I don't deal with macOS very often so I'm not too aware of any bugs/oddball situations like this.

I've tried using Chrome and Safari, both with the same results.

Any insight on this would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I took some screen shots to show the problem i'm having with macOS and compared to what it should look like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/owctR.jpg

Comment: You say MacOS but then describe the issue as occuring on mobile. I'm confused.

Comment: If the `line-height` is set using length units, it will inherit as an absolute length. E.G. a child with `font-size:15px` in a parent with `font-size:10px; line-height:1.3em` will have a line height of 13px. Does that explain what you're seeing? The solution would be to set the line height in unitless amounts such as `1.3`.

Comment: @denmch This problem only happens on macOS. By mobile I mean when I shrink the browser, so mobile emulator using the web console. I should have been more specific.

Comment: @MrLister I posted a imgur link that will better show what I'm dealing with.